# How to generate a unique ssh key for a GitLab group?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitolite, mirror

I have setup a push mirroring from GitLab to my own server (which runs Gitolite). For the mirror to be successful, I need to add the ssh key from the repository on GitLab to the Gitolite config. This part works.

[image: Copy ssh key by repo works]

However, I have 64 repositories that need to be mirrored across 2 GitLab groups. I can mirror them using a unique ssh key for every repo, but I would find it easier to have 1 ssh key for each group (so 2 of them in my case) so that it would be much easier to maintain.

I did not find how to generate such a key for a group on GitLab. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I dont think there is way yet in gitlab to manage it using group keys.